# How to load a non modal form on the inbuilt task pane of the MS Word using VB6?

Tags: ms-word, vb6

We are creating a ribbon bar for MS Word. When the user clicks on a button in  the ribbon bar, a non modal form appears. **We need to load it on the inbuilt task pane of MS Word**. Currently it loads on top of Word and does not get automatically minimized when we minimize Word.

We are using VB6 for development. Task pane of MS Word is highlighted in red color.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: OK, task pane contains the **search pane** and more panes. Are you tryiong to  add a **<costom> pane** with your addin ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to add a custom task pane using IDTExtensibility2. But I am unable to use VSTO for this because we are doing  the application using VB6. Could you please give me any guidence to create a custom task pane using VB6.  I searched a lot about it but could not find a suitable reference and guidence.

Comment: I would try to record a Word macro that does what your after, then you can adjust the VBA code to your needs and incorporate into addin using Word Automation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188009/discussion-between-siyon-dp-and-sanuththara).

Comment: You can't load a VB6 "into" Word's task pane. And the VBA suggestion is not valid - VBA can't work with custom task panes, etc. I'm afraid I have no experience implementing IDTExtensibility2 with task panes in VB6 or I'd try to help. FWIW though if you can find discussions that use VB.NET (*not* VSTO) and combine that with the information otherwise available for using the interface in VB6 that will probably be your best bet.

Answer (score -2):

The fastests way to solve such Office customization problems is: 
1. Record a Word macro that does what your after
2. Customize the macro VBA code to your needs
3. Incorporate it into the addin using Word Automation.

Comment: Since the OP is programming in VB6 and wants a custom task pane VBA is of no use. VBA *cannot* generate custom task panes, only Add-ins based on the IDTExtensibility2 interface can do that.